# Opensaml error receiving correct unmarshaller

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, marshalling, opensaml

I am running this code at opensaml2.6

```
Element metadataRoot = document.getDocumentElement();

// Unmarshall
UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshaller(metadataRoot);
if (unmarshaller == null) {
    System.out.println("Error receiving unmarshaller for this document.");
    return;
}
```

For the document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><saml2:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
```

`Unmarshaller` return a `null`, Can you help me to undertand how are the criterias to lookup the correct `Unmarshaller` and how this works at opensaml?

Comment: I found that there is not unmarshallers register as there is not initialization in the library:

Important piece of code:

  // Initialize the library
  DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found that there is not unmarshallers register as there is not initialization in the library:

Important piece of code:

```
// Initialize the library
DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();
```

Comment: Thank you Pegerto,you save my day

Comment: I use OpenSaml3 where this would be: `InitializationService.initialize()` but i still get null from the MarshallerFactory. Anyone can help?

Comment: @Goblins, I have no luck either.
I followed this code for initialization in OpenSAML3:
https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/master/support/cas-server-support-saml-core/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/support/saml/OpenSamlConfigBean.java

Then unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshallers() return 9 unmarshallers (e.g. integer, boolean, string), but none for the ones I care about.

Answer (score 5):

In OpenSAML3 you have to first make sure to include the `opensaml-saml-impl` artifact in your dependencies, since all the marshallers and unmarshallers are implemented there.

Then, as @Goblins and @Pegerto pointed out, you have to call `InitializationService.initialize()`. I have found this link to be useful for doing a correct initialization when using Dependency Injection https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/master/support/cas-server-support-saml-core-api/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/support/saml/OpenSamlConfigBean.java