# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

I am using openSAML to authenticate SAML Response from an Identity Provider (IdP). As the first step, I am converting the DOM response from the IdP to a openSAML XMLObject. I am using the following code:

```
Base64 base64 = new Base64();
byte[] base64DecodedResponse = base64.decode(responseMessage);

ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64DecodedResponse);

DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document document = docBuilder.parse(is);
Element element = document.getDocumentElement();

UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshaller(element);

if (unmarshaller == null)
    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not obtain a SAML unmarshaller");

XMLObject obj = unmarshaller.unmarshall(element);
if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Response))
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unmarshaller return not SAML response");
```

This code gave me IllegalStateException: Could not obtain a SAML unmarshaller. On googling I found this : [Opensaml error receiving correct unmarshaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066183/opensaml-error-receiving-correct-unmarshaller) where Pegerto suggested bootstrapping the unmarshaller registers. So, I added the following code:

```
try {
    DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();
    generator = new SecureRandomIdentifierGenerator();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now this is giving:

```
Jun 19, 2015 2:58:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/testSAML] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opensaml/DefaultBootstrap] with root cause
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap
```

I already have `import org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap;` in my code 
 and added opensaml-2.2.3.jar in my classpath.

Can someone help me with this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

The jar files should be in the WEB-INF/lib/ folder. It is a web application project.