# How to test/debug Decrypting Encrypted Assertion using OpenSAML 2 and Java?

Tags: java, encryption, saml-2.0, public-key-encryption, opensaml

I am trying to write a Java app together with OpenSAML2 (2.6.6) to decrypt an encrypted assertion, but I am getting:

```
[main] ERROR org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter - Failed to decrypt EncryptedKey, valid decryption key could not be resolved
[main] ERROR org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter - Failed to decrypt EncryptedData using either EncryptedData KeyInfoCredentialResolver or EncryptedKeyResolver + EncryptedKey KeyInfoCredentialResolver
[main] ERROR org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter - SAML Decrypter encountered an error decrypting element content
```

Here's my Java code (sorry it still has lots of debug output):

```
/*
 * ****************************************************************************************************
 * Original source from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422545/decrypting-encrypted-assertion-using-saml-2-0-in-java-using-opensaml
 * And hint about needed to add DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap() for OpenSAML 2.x: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066183/opensaml-error-receiving-correct-unmarshaller
 * And hing about chain resolvers: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter
 * ****************************************************************************************************
 * ****************************************************************************************************
 * ****************************************************************************************************
 * ****************************************************************************************************
 */
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.Assertion;
import org.opensaml.saml2.core.EncryptedAssertion;
import org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter;
import org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.EncryptedElementTypeEncryptedKeyResolver;
import org.opensaml.xml.Configuration;
import org.opensaml.xml.encryption.ChainingEncryptedKeyResolver;
import org.opensaml.xml.encryption.EncryptedKeyResolver;
import org.opensaml.xml.encryption.InlineEncryptedKeyResolver;
import org.opensaml.xml.encryption.SimpleRetrievalMethodEncryptedKeyResolver;
import org.opensaml.xml.io.Unmarshaller;
import org.opensaml.xml.io.UnmarshallerFactory;
import org.opensaml.xml.parse.BasicParserPool;
import org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver;
import org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.BasicX509Credential;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class test_opensaml {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String PROGVERSION = "V1.00";

        String xmlFileName = "";
        String privateKeyFileName = "";

        System.out.println("test_opensaml " + PROGVERSION);

        if(args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Command line is: java test_opensaml <signed_samlassertion_xml> <private_key_der>");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        xmlFileName = args[0];
        privateKeyFileName = args[1];

        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(test_opensaml.class);
        logger.info("xmlFileName=[" + xmlFileName + "]");
        logger.info("privateKeyFileName=[" + privateKeyFileName + "]\n");

        try {
            // Initialize the library
            DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("** ERROR ** - ERROR WHILE Executing DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap() - e=[" + e + "]");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        // Load the XML file and parse it.
        File xmlFile = new File(xmlFileName);
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("** ERROR ** - ERROR WHILE LOADING ASSERTION XML FILE - e=[" + e + "]");
            System.exit(-1);
        }


        BasicParserPool parserPoolManager = new BasicParserPool();

        Document document = null;
        Element metadataRoot = null;
        try {
            document = parserPoolManager.parse(inputStream);
            metadataRoot = document.getDocumentElement();
            System.out.println("metadataRoot.getNodeName()=[" + metadataRoot.getNodeName() + "]");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("** ERROR ** - ERROR WHILE CREATING DOCUMENT FROM XML FILE - e=[" + e + "]");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory = null;
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = null;
        EncryptedAssertion encryptedAssertion = null;

        try {
            // Unmarshall
            unmarshallerFactory = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("** ERROR ** - ERROR WHILE CREATING UNMARSHALLFACTORY - e=[" + e + "]");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        if (unmarshallerFactory == null) {
            System.out.println("unmarshallerFactory is null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("unmarshallerFactory is OK/NOT-null");
        }

        try {
            // Unmarshall
            unmarshaller = unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshaller(metadataRoot);
            if (unmarshaller == null) {
                System.out.println("unmarshaller is null");
            } else {
                System.out.println("unmarshaller is OK/NOT-null");
            }

            System.out.println("unmarshaller.getClass().getname=[" + unmarshaller.getClass().getName() + "]");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("** ERROR ** - ERROR WHILE CREATING UNMARSHALLER - e=[" + e + "]");
            System.exit(-1);
        }


        try {
            // Unmarshall
            encryptedAssertion = (EncryptedAssertion)unmarshaller.unmarshall(metadataRoot);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("** ERROR ** - ERROR CREATING ENCRYPTEDASSERTION BY UNMARSHALLING - e=[" + e + "]");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        System.out.println("SUCCESS - CREATED ENCRYPTEDASSERTION BY UNMARSHALLING!!");
        System.out.println("Will now try to load the PRIVATE KEY FILE...");

        // Load the private key file.
        File privateKeyFile = new File(privateKeyFileName);
        FileInputStream inputStreamPrivateKey = null;
        byte[] encodedPrivateKey = null;
        try {
            inputStreamPrivateKey = new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile);
            encodedPrivateKey = new byte[(int)privateKeyFile.length()];
            inputStreamPrivateKey.read(encodedPrivateKey);
            inputStreamPrivateKey.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("** ERROR ** - ERROR WHILE READING PRIVATE KEY FROM FILE - e=[" + e + "]");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        System.out.println("SUCCESS - READ/INPUT THE PRIVATE KEY FILE!!");

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = null;
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = null;
        try {
            // Create the private key.
            privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivateKey);
            privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey)KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("** ERROR ** - ERROR WHILE CREATING PRIVATE KEY - e=[" + e + "]");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        System.out.println("SUCCESS - CREATING THE PRIVATE KEY INSTANCE!!");



        ChainingEncryptedKeyResolver keyResolver = new ChainingEncryptedKeyResolver();
        keyResolver.getResolverChain().add(new InlineEncryptedKeyResolver());
        keyResolver.getResolverChain().add(new EncryptedElementTypeEncryptedKeyResolver());
        keyResolver.getResolverChain().add(new SimpleRetrievalMethodEncryptedKeyResolver());
        System.out.println("Built a list of encrypted key resolvers...");

        boolean successfulDecryption = false;

        // Create the credentials.
        BasicX509Credential decryptionCredential = new BasicX509Credential();
        decryptionCredential.setPrivateKey(privateKey);

        StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver resolver = new StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver(decryptionCredential);

        // Create a decrypter.
        Decrypter decrypter = new Decrypter(null, resolver, keyResolver);
        decrypter.setRootInNewDocument(true);
        // Decrypt the assertion.
        Assertion decryptedAssertion = null;
        System.out.println("WILL NOW TRY TO DECRYPT THE ENCRYPTED ASSERTION...");
        try
        {
            decryptedAssertion = decrypter.decrypt(encryptedAssertion);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("** ERROR ** - ERROR WHILE DECRYPTING THE ASSERTION - e=[" + e + "]");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println("SUCCESS - DECRYPTED THE ENCRYPTED ASSERTION - will now dump out the decrypted assertion...!!");
        System.out.println("decryptedAssertion.toString=[" + decryptedAssertion.toString() + "]");
        System.out.println("Finished...");
        System.exit(0);
    } // end main()

}
```

When I run that with a test signed assertion (XML) and the private key, I am getting the following output.  This is being run under Eclipse and using Java 1.8 build 201:

```
test_opensaml V1.00
[main] INFO test_opensaml - xmlFileName=[E:\ECLIPSE-WORKSPACES\opensaml\opensaml\data\encrypted_assertion.xml]
[main] INFO test_opensaml - privateKeyFileName=[E:\ECLIPSE-WORKSPACES\opensaml\opensaml\data\geoaxis-gxaccess.com.private-key.der]

metadataRoot.getNodeName()=[saml:EncryptedAssertion]
unmarshallerFactory is OK/NOT-null
unmarshaller is OK/NOT-null
unmarshaller.getClass().getname=[org.opensaml.saml2.core.impl.EncryptedAssertionUnmarshaller]
SUCCESS - CREATED ENCRYPTEDASSERTION BY UNMARSHALLING!!
Will now try to load the PRIVATE KEY FILE...
SUCCESS - READ/INPUT THE PRIVATE KEY FILE!!
SUCCESS - CREATING THE PRIVATE KEY INSTANCE!!
Built a list of encrypted key resolvers...
WILL NOW TRY TO DECRYPT THE ENCRYPTED ASSERTION...
[main] ERROR org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter - Error decrypting encrypted key
org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLEncryptionException: Unwrapping failed
Original Exception was java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unwrapping failed
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.decryptKey(XMLCipher.java:1539)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:708)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:639)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptUsingResolvedEncryptedKey(Decrypter.java:794)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:535)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToList(Decrypter.java:453)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:414)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:141)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decrypt(Decrypter.java:69)
    at test_opensaml.main(test_opensaml.java:193)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unwrapping failed
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineUnwrap(RSACipher.java:445)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.unwrap(Cipher.java:2549)
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.decryptKey(XMLCipher.java:1537)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadOAEP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineUnwrap(RSACipher.java:440)
    ... 11 more
[main] ERROR org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter - Failed to decrypt EncryptedKey, valid decryption key could not be resolved
[main] ERROR org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter - Failed to decrypt EncryptedData using either EncryptedData KeyInfoCredentialResolver or EncryptedKeyResolver + EncryptedKey KeyInfoCredentialResolver
[main] ERROR org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter - SAML Decrypter encountered an error decrypting element content
org.opensaml.xml.encryption.DecryptionException: Failed to decrypt EncryptedData
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:546)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToList(Decrypter.java:453)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:414)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:141)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decrypt(Decrypter.java:69)
    at test_opensaml.main(test_opensaml.java:193)
** ERROR ** - ERROR WHILE DECRYPTING THE ASSERTION - e=[org.opensaml.xml.encryption.DecryptionException: Failed to decrypt EncryptedData]
```

Since this is (for me, at least) new and untested code, I was wondering how I can diagnose this problem further?

Is there some additional logging or something that might help to find out what is wrong or pinpoint the problem?

I know that this is going to sound a little unusual, but also, FYI, I was given the signed assertion and private key that I am using to test right now, by a third party, so I am actually not 100% sure if they are good, so I was wondering if maybe there is somewhere I could get/download a known-good encrypted assertion example together with the corresponding private key, so that I could try to test my code above with known-good data?

Thanks,
Jim

EDIT:  Sorry I forgot to include a snippet of the encrypted assertion that I have been using to test:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<saml:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" Id="_332ec9de74ee4a8b97b84694edb58ba9" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<xenc:EncryptedKey Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" Id="_d32f036453ed438b84783a21a2e2cca7">
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"/>
<xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:CipherValue>Rfn5PDApVSF3wTBgsiQsFn5rybj...EZoHpGvxDPv5kAhVw==</xenc:CipherValue>
</xenc:CipherData>
</xenc:EncryptedKey>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:CipherValue>FTk8D8nGOTuZsunGifMEHtj...xiAvwSQ=</xenc:CipherValue>
</xenc:CipherData>
</xenc:EncryptedData>
</saml:EncryptedAssertion>
```

EDIT 2: For someone who is familiar with OpenSAML and SAML:  Is there something wrong with the signed assertion above?  I've been doing some additional testing, and it seems like none of the resolvers are able to find the encryption key and I noticed that the ds:Keyinfo is embedded inside xenc:EncryptedData, at the same level as the xenc:CipherData.  Is that a normal structure, and which of the chained resolvers is supposed to find that ds:Keyinfo?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I was finally get this working as-is, once I found the correct private key to match the sample encrypted assertion.

Answer (score 0):

With your changes, I got KEY LENGTH known errors, issue resolved after following the below link

org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLEncryptionException: Illegal key size
Original Exception was java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size

https://faq.miniorange.com/knowledgebase/i-am-getting-org-apache-xml-security-encryption-xmlencryptionexception-illegal-key-size-exception-sso/