# SAML EncryptedAssertion Decryption failing - Error decrypting encrypted key

Tags: java, encryption, saml, opensaml

I am facing issues with the encryption.I had received a response from idp,and encountered a problem in decryption
This is to convert a string to an XML object

```
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = getDocumentBuilder(false, true, null);
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedResponse.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
Document document = docBuilder.parse(inputStream);
Element metadataRoot = document.getDocumentElement();
```

Unmarshall

```
UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory = XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getUnmarshallerFactory();
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshaller(metadataRoot);
Response response = (Response)unmarshaller.unmarshall(metadataRoot);
```

Decrypter

```
EncryptedAssertion encryptedAssertion = null;
Assertion assertion = null;
List<EncryptedAssertion> encryptedAssertions = response.getEncryptedAssertions();
encryptedAssertion=encryptedAssertions.get(0);
StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver keyInfoCredentialResolver = new StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver(SPCredentials.getCredential());
Decrypter decrypter = new Decrypter(null, keyInfoCredentialResolver, new InlineEncryptedKeyResolver());
decrypter.setRootInNewDocument(true);
assertion= decrypter.decrypt(encryptedAssertion);
```

The error message appears on this line

```
assertion= decrypter.decrypt(encryptedAssertion);
```

This is the JKS registration method

```
static {
        try {
            KeyStore keystore = readKeystoreFromFile(KEY_STORE_PATH, KEY_STORE_PASSWORD);
            Map<String, String> passwordMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            passwordMap.put(KEY_ENTRY_ID, KEY_STORE_ENTRY_PASSWORD);
            KeyStoreCredentialResolver resolver = new KeyStoreCredentialResolver(keystore, passwordMap);
            Criterion criterion = new EntityIdCriterion(KEY_ENTRY_ID);
            CriteriaSet criteriaSet = new CriteriaSet();
            criteriaSet.add(criterion);
            credential = resolver.resolveSingle(criteriaSet);
        } catch (ResolverException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong reading credentials", e);
        }
    }

    private static KeyStore readKeystoreFromFile(String pathToKeyStore, String keyStorePassword) {
        try {
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            InputStream inputStream = SPCredentials.class.getResourceAsStream(pathToKeyStore);
            keystore.load(inputStream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            inputStream.close();
            return keystore;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong reading keystore", e);
        }
    }
```

This is an error message

```
2021-10-21 17:50:46,466 [ERROR] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter [Decrypter.java : 717] - Error decrypting encrypted key
org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLEncryptionException: Unwrapping failed
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.decryptKey(XMLCipher.java:1532)
    at org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:711)
    at org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:643)
    at org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter.decryptUsingResolvedEncryptedKey(Decrypter.java:781)
    at org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:539)
    at org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter.decryptDataToList(Decrypter.java:452)
    at org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:412)
    at org.opensaml.saml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:176)
    at org.opensaml.saml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decrypt(Decrypter.java:104)
    at com.shell.web.controller.system.sso.SysSSoController.test1(SysSSoController.java:206)
    at com.shell.web.controller.system.sso.SysSSoController.test2(SysSSoController.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.alibaba.druid.support.http.WebStatFilter.doFilter(WebStatFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.shell.common.filter.RepeatableFilter.doFilter(RepeatableFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at com.shell.framework.security.filter.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unwrapping failed
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineUnwrap(RSACipher.java:445)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.unwrap(Cipher.java:2550)
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.decryptKey(XMLCipher.java:1530)
    ... 111 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadOAEP(RSAPadding.java:499)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:293)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineUnwrap(RSACipher.java:440)
    ... 113 common frames omitted
2021-10-21 17:50:46,512 [ERROR] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter [Decrypter.java : 654] - Failed to decrypt EncryptedKey, valid decryption key could not be resolved
2021-10-21 17:50:46,515 [ERROR] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter [Decrypter.java : 547] - Failed to decrypt EncryptedData using either EncryptedData KeyInfoCredentialResolver or EncryptedKeyResolver + EncryptedKey KeyInfoCredentialResolver
2021-10-21 17:50:46,520 [ERROR] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.opensaml.saml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter [Decrypter.java : 178] - SAML Decrypter encountered an error decrypting element content
org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.DecryptionException: Failed to decrypt EncryptedData
    at org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:550)
    at org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter.decryptDataToList(Decrypter.java:452)
```

I want to know where this error occurred and how to solve it

Comment: 'BadPadding' for RSA (including OAEP) usually means you're trying to decrypt with a private key that doesn't match the public key used to encrypt. Maybe you're using the wrong keystore or entry, or maybe the sender is using the wrong key probably from a wrong or superseded certificate. If so, dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621039/how-to-test-debug-decrypting-encrypted-assertion-using-opensaml-2-and-java . XMLenc EncryptedKey can contain info about the cert used; if your sender (the idp) does so, you should check that info against your cert and/or key.